# Simple Addon 50 lines - Crash blender - what I do bad?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, error

I start to learn Python and Blender. But can't figure out what I do bad here.
The code is :

```
bl_info = {
    "name" : "HELLO WORLD",
    "author" : "Author",
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0), "version" : (0, 0, 1),
}

import bpy

class LODP_CM_OT_set_cam ( bpy.types.Operator ) : 
    bl_idname       = "lodp_cm.set_cam"
    bl_label        = "Set camera brush"

    def execute( self : bpy.types.Operator , context : bpy.types.Context ) : 
        obj  = bpy.context.active_object

        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = None
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

        mod : bpy.types.DynamicPaintModifier = obj.modifiers.new( "Dynamic Paint", "DYNAMIC_PAINT" )
        mod.ui_type = "BRUSH"
        
        # CRITICAL ERROR -  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION - 0x00007FF73793DDB0
        bpy.ops.dpaint.type_toggle( type="BRUSH" ) 
        # CRITICAL ERROR -  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION - 0x00007FF73793DDB0

        return {"FINISHED"}
# end class LODP_CM_OT_set_cam

class LODP_CM_PT_main ( bpy.types.Panel ) : 
    bl_label        = "HELLO WORLD PANEL"
    bl_idname       = "LODP_PT_main"
    bl_space_type   = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type  = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context      = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator( LODP_CM_OT_set_cam.bl_idname )
#

classes = [ LODP_CM_OT_set_cam, LODP_CM_PT_main, ]

def register():
    global classes
    for klass in classes : bpy.utils.register_class( klass )
#
def unregister():
    global classes
    for klass in classes : bpy.utils.unregister_class( klass )
    classes.clear()
#
if not __package__ : register()
```

representative gif :

[image]

After trying to get the code of the error or something,
get : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION - 0x00007FF73793DDB0, exit code 11

Is a mistake, bug, bad syntaxis, another thing? , but since I'm a newcomer, I have my doubts.

Comment: For one, don't use boy.context in an operator. Ude the context you receive in the context parameter.

Answer (score 3):

**Is it as simple as it could be?.**

*A TL;DR comment turned into answer:*

Doesn't crash for me... but does throw errors. Some of the issues as I see them.

Sure it's a simple little addon, but.. appears to be some added and IMO unnecessary complexity added too. (bling).

Is there really any need to type hint the *usual suspects*  and  familiar arguments of  `self, context` ?

```
def execute( self : bpy.types.Operator , context : bpy.types.Context )
```

Let's look at  `Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator Simple` and make a small change

```
def execute(self, context):
    print(type(self))
    main(context)
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

output

```
<class '__main__.SimpleOperator'>
<bpy_struct, Object("Armature") at 0x7f1e0c715008>
```

*ie* the operator type is not an instance of  `bpy.types.Operator`

**Any need to toggle the active object?**

There is no need to toggle the active object with

```
context.view_layer.objects.active = None
context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
```

and  since context is an argument of method there is never any need to see `bpy.context`

**Dynamic Paint Modifier.**

Once a dynamic paint modifier is added to an object, it cannot be added again.  If you try and do so again it will not add a modifier and return `None`. (`NoneType`) is not an instance of `bpy.types.DynamicPaintModifier`

**Main thread.**

Any benefit in using `if not __package__` vs `if __name__ == "__main__"` ?  Will it always equate?

Comment: mmm since it is a development-learning environment, in order to enable vscode autocompletion I had to put something. What you say is very good ...
even so. without removing all the tracks, nor the unnecessary code. changing the order ... always crash.

I already download another version of blender. Likewise. tested on clean installation of 2.91.1 st / 2.91.2 st / 2.83 lts